# Transactions - Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I am experiencing a "Transaction timeout exceeded" issue in the code snippet below

```
     using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) }))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        segregationAssignment = new SegregationAssignment(dbContext).Assign(rmaU);

                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        scope.Complete();
                        scope.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException eb)
                    {
                        scope.Dispose();
                        return RedirectToAction("Details", details).WithErrorMessage(string.Format(Validations.not_possible_to_operation,
                            details.IsConfirmSegregate ? Buttons.segregate.ToLower() : Buttons.refuse.ToLower(), Models.rma_u));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        scope.Dispose();
                        return RedirectToAction("Details", details).WithErrorMessage(string.Format(Validations.not_possible_to_operation,
                            details.IsConfirmSegregate ? Buttons.segregate.ToLower() : Buttons.refuse.ToLower(), Models.rma_u));
                    }
                }
```

Inside it we have some additions of objects in context in the Assign method, only that. I do not understand why you're giving timeout in a process that takes a maximum of 10 minutes.

If you can help me, I'll be grateful. We are using version 5 of entity.

Comment: Aside: calling `scope.Dispose` explicitly is neither necessary nor useful. The `using` takes care of it regardless of what happens in the block. (That's more or less its entire purpose.)

Comment: Aside: `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` is usually a bad idea -- no locks will be taken to ensure data integrity at all. That's especially dubious when you're trying to have an all-or-nothing update by wrapping things in a transaction. Consider using snapshot isolation if locking is an issue in the database, or else just stick to the default `ReadCommitted`. ([Some background material](https://blogs.sentryone.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).)

Comment: What's the *exact* error you get (exception type, message) and how long after starting the operation does it appear? "Transaction" is a loaded term. It's worth to confirm that the exception in question is really produced by the database operation -- it could be produced by another subsystem or by EF itself. If it is a DB error, you can break out SQL Profiler to trace what's happening on the DB end.

Comment: The inner exception gives this message "The underlying provider failed in Open."